# Triggering GitLab Job Conditionally Based on File Existence

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can I trigger a GitLab job to run only if a certain file exists in the repository, and not run if the file is not present?

I tried using `rules` and I got an error:

```
build-image:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ...
  rules:
    - if: $CLIENT_EXISTS == "1"
```

I got

```
This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:build-image config key may not be used with `rules`:
```